# What does it mean "positive" or "negative" polarity in VGA's HSynch and Vsynch?

Tags: timing, vga

I have been trying to study how VGA signals work and I stumbled upon this [this page](http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing) with all the different VGA timings.

What isn't clear to me is what it means by "polarity horizontal sync pulse is positive".

Does it mean the hsync signal stays low and the pulse is positive or vice versa?

Comment: "sync pulse is positive" means the sync pulse is positive.

Comment: That's what I thought too but my confusion comes from the fact than I saw a youtube video (Ben eater's video card) in which he considers the pulse negative despite the fact the timings from the apge I linked says 'positive polarity'. And he managed to make it work!

Answer (score 3):

The sync polarity defines what is the idle and active state of the sync signal.

In your question, positive means the sync signal will idle at logic low level, and is shortly active on high level, creating a positive sync pulse.

In comparison, the industry standard VGA 640 x 480 @ 59.94 Hz, both sync polarities are negative, so the sync signals idle at logic high level, and shortly go active at logic low level.

Comment: I asked this question because I saw a youtube video about a guy building a "video card" which displays an image via VGA cable. Explaining his project he uses the standard 800x600 60 Hz which in the link I posted above specifies a positive polarity for synch pulses, yet in the video he builds a generator of signals which are normally HIGH and go low for a short period, and he is able to make it work. So I am kinda confused why did it work if the standard specifies the opposite...

Comment: How are you sure that the scoped signal was exactly the one that went to VGA connector, instead of some other intermediate signal before inverting buffer for example (I have not watched the video)? Even if the polarity was wrong, many displays don't care about the polarity, if the signal timing otherwise matches a certain format. It is also possible that the display does care and triggers on the wrong signal edge, but it will just shift the picture by the length of the pulses (128 pixels and 4 lines), and the shift might be compensated on the transmitting end.

Comment: @AndreaBianchi I have exactly the same doubt as you had from seeing the same video and it not matching the info on that same page.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, in the early days of VGA, using the polarity of the horizontal and vertical sync pulses as a 2-bit binary code indicated to the monitor what resolution was being sent. This allowed for 4 possible values. You can use a capacitor and an XOR gate to convert the pulse to always be positive, and use the input from the capacitor as the "information" on the polarity of each sync signal. Then you could use those values to toggle on the parts of the rest of the circuit you wanted active depending on the specified resolution. This allowed for the monitor to not have very sophisticated electronics, but still do its job. Later, there were so many resolutions (SVGA, XGA, etc.) that monitors needed to be more intelligent and determine the resolution outright by analyzing the signal (counting lines between v-syncs, etc.) so they would use this information to override an incorrect polarity. So Ben Eater may have bene using the wrong polarity, but his monitor might have been modern enough, and therefore smart enough, to override that info, and do the right thing anyway.